# How add custom functionality after product review?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

Hi I am new to Magento

How to add custom functionality to Product review ??

I need to send a mail with discount coupons to user's email id once user has reviewed product.

How can I do this functionality please help me

Comment: Check into the `review_safe_after` event, or possibly extend the product controller class `app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php`

Comment: when you want to send mail to customer .....please explain properly

Comment: @TimHallman. You should write your comment as an answer. Include a link to a page explaining how to create an observer and it's the perfect answer.

Comment: @Marius, thanks, I added an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an observer to the `review_save_after` event in your `config.xml` file like this:

```
<events>
    <review_save_after>
        <observers>
            <namespace_module>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Review_Observer</class>
                <method>send_mail_after_review</method>
            </namespace_module>
         </observers>
    <review_save_after>
</events>
```

Note: you will need to customize the above code and create your observer class to meet your needs. For more information on Magento observers see [this link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method).

Alternatively, you may be able to extend the product controller class in

`app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php`

Then add your mail function after the line that looks like:

`$session->addSuccess($this->__('Your review has been accepted for moderation.'));`

There is some useful information [here](http://www.atwix.com/magento/overriding-observers/) pertaining to overriding Magento observers.